# Javascript to set dialog title bar color after dialog has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dialog

I have built a js dialog to act as a color selector.  Everything is working well, except that when they user picks the color swatch, I cannot seem to set the color of the dialog title bar.

Would also appreciate how one stops the parent window that called the dialog from being dimmed or opacity set so it appears dim.

When the user selects a color sample within the dialog a function outside the dialog is called to temporarily set the colors of the calling window.  The code is below:

```
function changeColor(themeColor) {
    // set colors on parent window that called the dialog
    $("#top-wrapper").css("background-color", themeColor);
    $("#md-page-head").css("background-color", themeColor);
    $("#bottom-wrapper").css("background-color", themeColor);

    // looking for code that would go here to set the dialog's title bar color
    //  have tried various iterations to no avail
}
```

Dialog code looks like this:

```
$('#qktheme').dialog({
    width: 500,
    resizable: false,
    show: 'slide',
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    buttons: [{
        text: "Save",
        tabIndex:-1,
        'class':'dialog3_buttons',
        click: function(event) {
            // save the new theme color choice - to be coded
            $(this).dialog("close");
            return true;
        }
    }, {
        text: "Cancel",
        tabIndex:-1,
        'class':'dialog3_buttons',
        click: function(event) {
            // put back the original theme color - to be coded
            $(this).dialog("close");
            return false;
        }
    }]
})
.height("auto");
```

Comment: if you don't want backdrop use `modal:false`. Not really clear how the coloring is supposed to work

Comment: Thanks - that works perfect for the secondary issue.   Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could use F12 developer tools to inspect the element of the dialog's title bar and check the id (or class) applied to the element, and then you could use jQuery id or class selector to find the title bar and set color for it.

Comment: I have the id to the element.  Attempts to use js to set the color have not worked thus far.  Need more specific advise.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to my problem.

```
$(".ui-dialog").find(".ui-widget-header").css("background", "darkgreen");
```